# Send emails from Domain alias in google apps

Tags: email, g-suite

I have a primary domain in Google apps and a few domains setup as domain alias. I can recieve emails on username@primary and at username@domain-alias

(All these steps have been completed

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295)

However I can not find out a way to send emails via the domain alias. (In the compose email window.)

I can add these domains via add account, but then I need to update the smtp settings each time I update the password.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Gmail help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22370) on my Google Apps account:

> 1. Sign in to your Google Apps email.
> 2. Click the gear icon in the upper-right and select Gmail settings along the top of any page, and select the Accounts tab.
> 3. Under Send mail as, click Add another email address.
> 4. In the Email address field, enter your name and alternate email address.
> 5. Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it.
> 6. Locate the message from Gmail. Open it and and either click the link contained in the message or enter the confirmation code in the Accounts section of your Google Apps email settings.

So, if your domain name is **mydomainname.com** and your alias was **alias.mydomainname.com** then **user@mydomainname.com** would have to add a send-to address for **user@alias.mydomainname.com**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I configured it as such and it works when using webmail.
Do you know if when using a Outlook (not in IMAP mode) would the replies sent via the Outlook account user@mydomainname.com show up to the end user as from user@alias.mydomainname.com (ofc assuming it is a reply to a msg sent to user@alias.mydomainname.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as > Click "Send mail as another address"

after that it should be self explanatory.

Comment: That doenst help me as mentioned in last line: "I can add these domains via add account, but then I need to update the smtp settings each time I update the password."

Comment: I have been doing this from quite some time and it should work for you without update of SMTP settings. Let me understand your question. You have a@xyz.com, b@xyz.com and c@xyz.com. You want to send emails from a@xyz.com and they should look like coming from b@xyz.com and c@xyz.com right? If yes, then what I have mentioned above should work for you. Remember you need to go into your email account (a@xyz.com) settings and NOT your dashboard settings.